# Two drop-down first will have 3 Sobject and second will show the respective fields of above selected object. It's not working after selecting object

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

Aura component

```
<aura:component controller="ObjectsFieldsList" implements="force:hasRecordId,force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
 <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
  <aura:attribute name='objectList' type='List' />     
  <aura:attribute name='OptList' type='List' />  
 <div class="slds-col">     
 <lightning:select aura:id="SobjectList" name="SobjectList" label="Select Object"
                            onchange="{!c.getfields}"
                            value="{!v.objectList}"
                          >
      <aura:iteration items='{!v.objectList}' var='obj'>
                            <option value="{!obj.key}" text="{!obj.value}" />
                        </aura:iteration>
     </lightning:select>
     </div>

    <div class="slds-col"> <lightning:select aura:id="FieldsList" name="FieldsList" label="Fields"
                            disabled="true">
         <aura:iteration items='{!v.Optlist}' var='obj'>
                            <option value="{!obj.key}" text="{!obj.value}" />
                        </aura:iteration>
        
        </lightning:select>    
    
    </div>
   
</aura:component>
```

Js controller

```
({
  
         doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
        // Create the action
        var action = component.get("c.getAllObjects");
        // Add callback behavior for when response is received
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            console.log(response.getReturnValue());
            if (state == "SUCCESS" && component.isValid()) {
               var allValues = response.getReturnValue();
                var lstOptions = []; 
                for (var i = 0; i < allValues.length; i++) {
                    lstOptions.push({
                        class: "optionClass",
                        value: allValues[i],
                        key: allValues[i]
                    });
            }
                 component.set("v.objectList", lstOptions);
            }
            else {
                console.log("Failed with state: " + state);
            }
        });
        // Send action off to be executed
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
    getfields: function(component, event, helper) {
    var action = component.get("c.getAllFields");//var selObject = component.find('selectObject').get('v.value');
      var userObj=component.find('SobjectList').get('v.value');
        action.setParams({
            "fld": userObj
        });
          // Add callback behavior for when response is received
      
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            console.log(response.getReturnValue());
            if (state == "SUCCESS") {
               var allfieldValues = response.getReturnValue();
               var opts=[]; 
                for (var i = 0; i < allfieldValues.length; i++) {
                    opts.push({
                        class: "optionClass",
                        value: allfieldValues[i],
                        key: allfieldValues[i]
                    });
            }
                 component.set("v.Optlist", opts);
            }
            else {
                console.log("Failed with state: " + state);
            }
        });
        // Send action off to be executed
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }  
})
```

Apex controller

```
public class ObjectsFieldsList {
   @AuraEnabled
    public static List<string> getAllObjects(){
        List<string> SObjectList = new List<string>();
        SObjectList.add('Account');
        SObjectList.add('Contact');
        SObjectList.add('Opportunity');
        return SObjectList;
    }
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<String> getAllFields(String fld){
        List<String> fieldList = new List<String>();
        Map<String,Schema.SObjectType> gd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
        Schema.SObjectType sobjType = gd.get(fld);
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult describeResult = sobjType.getDescribe();
        Map<String,Schema.SObjectField> fieldsMap = describeResult.fields.getMap();
        for(string str: fieldsMap.keySet()){
            fieldList.add(fieldsMap.get(str).getDescribe().getLabel());                
        }
        return fieldList;      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript is case sensitive. Make sure you're paying close attention to how you type:

```
<aura:attribute name="OptList" type="List" />
```

...

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.Optlist}" var="obj">
```

This will cause an error when trying to set the attribute. Adjust your code so that all instances of the attribute use the same case.